# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined, But it's defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I having trouble with this problem for hours ago. 
I wrote these in my Jquery function to check Value in Variable if it's exist or not.

```
console.log("in tr");
console.log(tmpRoomlistArray[c].room_name);
let roomName = tmpRoomlistArray[c].room_name;
```

When I ran and looked at Google Chrome Console. It shows results like this.

```
Rome  <<< In console.log It shows valid value                                   
in tr                                                       
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'room_name' of undefined << 
This is what happen when I assign in to a variable and this is what I need
```

What happen ?? I'm blind right now..

edit : edit question content

Answer (score 1):

I already solved it. It just a silly problem that I overlooked. It's about array index.

I just put

```
tmpRoomlistArray[c-1]
```

into my function and it worked. I think the solution is just rest more, So you could see the problem more clearly.

For those who want to know what happen just read it below.

I got a function that insert row in table, and this function have 2 parameters, which is an array. So this function will insert row continuously into the table. It won't stop until it reach the end of the array.

```
var day = ["1","2","3"];
var room = ["room1","room2","room3",....,"room16"] // 16 Elements;
var timeForHeader = ["08:00","09:00",....."20:00"] // 25 Elements; 

function addRow(paramDay,paramRoom){ 
 // this function will create many rows depends on paramRoom length and columns depends on length of time header.
   var dayLength = day.length;
   var roomLength = room.length;
   var timeForHeaderLength = timeForHeader.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < dayLength; i++)
   {
      // this is for rows
       for(var c = 0; c < timeForHeaderLength+1; c++)
       {
          // I made c +1 timeForHeaderLength because I want a header 
          //this is for column
          if(c == 0)
          { 
            // if c == 0 mean I will insert a header row element in my table
             var tr = $("<tr/>");
             var td = $("<td/>",{text:timeForHeader[0]+" - "+timeForHeader[1]}).appendTo(tr);
             ...
             ...
             var td23 = $("<td/>",{text:timeForHeader[23]+" - "+timeForHeader[24]}).appendTo(tr);
             $("#mytableId").append(tr);
          }else{
            // this row that contain room's name and content
            // and this is the part that cause me a problem.
            // in this else condition c must be 1-17 so when I access to tmpRoomlistArray that contains 16 Element
            // So right now You guys should know right. The tmpRoomlistArray's index must be 0 - 16


            // it worked when c is between 1 - 16, But it didn't work on the last c cause c is equal to 17
             console.log(tmpRoomlistArray[c].room_name);
            let roomName = tmpRoomlistArray[c].room_name;
            //It should be 
            let roomName = tmpRoomlistArray[c-1].room_name;
            // Hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahhaha
          }              
       }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tmpRoomlistArray[c] is coming as undefined.

Try to print:

```
  console.log(tmpRoomlistArray[c]);
```

or

```
 console.log(tmpRoomlistArray);
```

instead of

```
console.log(tmpRoomlistArray[c].room_name);
```

You can also use

```
  debugger
```

in javascript code to watch value of array.

Comment: Oh yeah, But if I want to assigned it to a variable, it showed "Uncaught TypeError:". 

I'm very sorry for uncleared question and language. I feel didn't good now, I've been coding for many hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use var instead of let?

Could let be looking for something more strongly typed?

Comment: How big is the whole script? Any way you could post it somewhere, or even better distill the problem down to a minimum test case and post that.

Comment: It have 255 lines.

I put all my code in this

https://jsfiddle.net/vf6rL66o/

It's pretty messy, cause I'm very new on programming.

Comment: The odd thing is you're getting that 'Rome', which is the room name? Then accessing again gives the error?

Comment: Delete the offending line, then retype it. Slight chance there's an odd character in there we can't see.

Comment: Also, try what Swati said to narrow it down.